# How can I do a non-USB clean install of Ventura on an M2 Air that came with Monterey?

Tags: install, monterey, ventura, macos

No matter what I do, I can't figure out how to do a clean install of Ventura.

If I go into Recovery, format the disk, and then exit disk utility, it only gives me an option to reinstall Monterey.

If I then upgrade to Ventura, go into Recovery, format the disk, and exit disk utility, it still only gives me an option to install Monterey.

I cannot do a USB install for reasons I won't go into here.

There must be a way to do a clean install of Ventura?

*Please don't ask me why I want to do a a clean install or waste time saying I don't need to.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Ventura by installing Ventura to a new APFS volume?

Comment: Why can't you do a USB install? Why not just install the OS from System Preferences from a 'normal' boot? Once you have installed Ventura, you can erase all content and settings (also in System Settings), which is the new method for a clean install. (E.g. there's no need to wipe and reinstall the OS, because it's read-only and can't be modified anyway.)

Comment: @Allan I am looking to upgrade, not downgrade. Not sure why you are sharing steps on how to get an older version. :/

Comment: @DavidAnderson I upgraded to Ventura by wiping HD, installing Montery and then upgrading to Ventura. But I can't do a clean install of Ventura.

Comment: @benwiggy I don't have USB-C flash drive, or any adapters nor do I want to buy. The erase content is one option but I really want to do a clean install.

Comment: As said, it's exactly the same as a clean install. The bit with any 'problem' is the Data volume. That's where any third-party software and user content is. The OS can't be modified in normal use, so there's no point in deleting it just to put it back.

Comment: In my case, the OS is modified. OS is installed, installation process pushes company specific content/changes to the OS stuff. For other macs, folks are able to do clean install of Ventura with USB.